# AllowUsers in sshd_config from multiple c class ranges

Tags: linux, sshd

Is there better (shorter) way to do this?

```
AllowUsers user@123.56.177.* user@123.56.178.* user@123.56.179.*
```

Something along the lines of...

```
AllowUsers user@123.56.177/178/179.*
```

Comment: Seems like it might be an answer, @mosvy!

Comment: Question: Would something that autogenerated this for you be sufficient? It might be worth using some form of config tool or `sed` to handle this for you.

Answer (score 1):

The man page says that you can write addresses in cidr (addr/len) format. Example:

```
AllowUsers user@192.168.176.0/22
```

Notice that that will not work with 'inconsistent' addresses (where the bits outside the mask are not all 0, eg. `192.168.177.0/22`) or with a mix of addr/len and wildcards (eg. `192.168.176.*/22`).

Answer (score 0):

[`AllowUsers`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/sshd_config.5.html) supports [patterns with wildcards](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/ssh_config.5.html#PATTERNS), and CIDR addresses. But I can't get them to work at the same time, and the patterns wouldn't be much help either, since the available wildcards are `?` and `*`, but not `[789]`.

So, it's probably easiest to just automatically generate the rules:

```
for i in {177..179}; do echo "AllowUsers user@123.56.$i.*" ; done
```

It doesn't say it in the documentation, but multiple `AllowUsers` lines seem to work ok.

Alternatively, in this case you might be able to use something like:

```
AllowUsers user@123.56.176.0/22
DenyUsers  user@123.56.176.0/24
```

or

```
AllowUsers !user@123.56.176.0/24,user@123.56.176.0/22
```